# Audio controls in lock screen with AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, audiokit, mpremotecommandcenter

I am using AudioKit to manage my sound engine in my app. I think AudioKit's settings are overriding something and I can't get lock screen audio controls. This is the code I have currently:

```
//Configure media control center
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the pause command
        return .success
    }

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        //Update your button here for the play command
        return .success
    }
```

I have this in a function which sets up all of my AudioKit settings but it doesn't work. Is there a special procedure for lock screen audio controls with AudioKit?

Answer (score 1):

you have to write these code in appdelegate to implement ：

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}catch{

}
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: I put this into my AppDelegate and nothing happened.

Comment: You have to rewrite this methord://MARK:-音乐播放相应后台状态
    override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        if (event?.type == .remoteControl) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Configs.remotePlayCotrolNotificaation), object: nil, userInfo: ["event":event!])
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind it's important to disable `.mixWithOthers`

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to rewrite this methord:
//MARK:-音乐播放相应后台状态
override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (event?.type == .remoteControl) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Configs.remotePlayCotrolNotificaation), object: nil, userInfo: ["event":event!])
    }
}
```